# instantiation and interface

Tags: c#, oop

I'm used to instantiate object as following:

```
type obj-name = new type();
```

and now I'm using

```
IList<string> str_element = new List<string>();
```

I was expecting to see something

```
IList<string> actors = new IList<string>();
```

can somebody give me some ideas why for interface instantiation is different here?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 4):

An interface is just that — an interface, or a specification of what methods should exist.
An interface does not contain any actual code.

Interfaces can only be used as types that hold concrete classes.
It doesn't make sense to create an instance of an interface, since there is nothing to instantiate.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't do `= new IList<string>()` is because `IList<T>` is an interface and you can't initialize interfaces as there is no body of code to call. I would reccomend doing

```
List<string> actors = new List<string>()
```

instead.

Comment: don't get me wrong this works but I was wondering but after these answers I remembered what I had read in OOP about interface!

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces define a contract, or set of functionality, that implementing classes must provide (at a minimum). By defining a variable of type `IList<T>`, you are really saying, "I don't care what the actual implementation is, it just needs to provide that functionality." This means you are divorcing the 'interface' and the 'implementation' in your calling code, which is a good thing.

The real power of interfaces is where you have pluggable code. If you were defining a library, rather than returning a `List<T>` instance, you could return an `IList<T>` instance (which AFAIK, is what the LINQ functionality does). This allows you to change the internal implementation of the object returned (it might be a linked list, or a B-Tree, or whatever), and calling code doesn't need to change.

Alot of the mocking libraries out there (e.g. NMock, Moq, etc) take advantage of interfaces and can generate implementing classes for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ: for example

This will give you something of a more Concrete Type.

```
using System.Linq;

IList<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
IEnumerable<Foo> sortedEnum = list.OrderBy(f=>f.Bar);
IList<Foo> sortedList = sortedEnum.ToList()
```

Comment: I know Cole I was just giving an example but it doesn't mean he doesn't want to sort.. I saw Actors so that's why I posted the example sorry..